# Cannot import a nested export in javascript module

Tags: javascript, javascript-import

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to import `readFileSync` and `writeFileSync` from the `rw` module, specifically from its `dash` "submodule".
I have tried the following

```js
import {readFileSync, writeFileSync} from 'rw/dash';
```

which gives me `error: Could not resolve "rw/dash"`.
I can access the functions I need with `import {dash} from 'rw';` and `dash.readFileSync`, but I'd rather import the functions directly.
I also tried other things like

```js
import {
  dash.readFileSync as readFileSync,
  dash.writeFileSync as writeFileSync
} from 'rw';
```

but dots don't seem to be allowed like this.

Any pointers are much appreciated.
Or if this is against the "spirit" of javascript let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind adding a second line, you can do this:

```js
import {dash} from 'rw';
const {readFileSync, writeFileSync} = dash;
```

The reason you can't import it with `from 'rw/dash'` is due to how that library [does it's exports](https://github.com/mbostock/rw).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is it about the library that makes this not work? Is their implementation unorthodox somehow?

Comment: Not really, just very specific.  `index.js` at the root of the project is the key.  It explicitly exports each file, and in the case of `lib/rw/dash.js`, it also exports specific things.  It was just a choice by the maintainer(s).